# Computing a Killing vector field from flow

Tags: differential-geometry

I am given the following manifold $N=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y>0\}$ with metric:

$$ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$$

There is a suggestion to take $z=x+iy$ and consider the transformations:

$$z\to z+c\,, \quad z\to cz\,,\quad z \to \frac{z}{cz+1}\,,\quad c\in \mathbb{R}$$

I have to find three independent Killing vector fields.

I think the idea is to define a flow from those transformations and then compute the Killing vectors associated to that flow. Is there any systematic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea. First, define
\begin{align}
\varphi_1(t,z) &= z + t &
\varphi_2(t,z) &= e^{2t}z &
\varphi_3(t,z) &= \dfrac{z}{tz +1}
\end{align}
They correspond to the matrices in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$, generating $1$-parameter subgroups
\begin{align}
A_1 &=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}&
A_2 &=\begin{pmatrix}
e^t & 0 \\
0 & e^{-t}
\end{pmatrix}&
A_3 &=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
t & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Show they are flows acting by isometry on the hyperbolic plane. Then, compute $X_i(z) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\varphi_i(t,z)$. They will be Killing vector fields.

For example, fix $z$ in the hyperbolic plane. Then the vector field $X_1(z)$ at $z$ is the tangent vector in $T_z\mathbb{H} \simeq \mathbb{C}$
$$
X_1(z) = \left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\varphi_1(t,z) = 1 = 1 + i\cdot 0 = \partial_x
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. On the last step you say that the Killing vector fields will be given by $\frac{d}{dt} \varphi_i(t,z)$. But for example, $\frac{d}{dt} \varphi_1(t,z)=z+1$. How do I get the vector field?

Comment: I added a line to highlight how to compute $X_1$. You did some error in the differentiation. Moreover, recall that you are working in the identity chart, so coordinates have to be translated into right vector fields while differentiating.